# Eisenstein series for discrete subgroups of SL(2,C)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

I am looking for a reference for Eisenstein series for discrete subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb C)$, in particular, finite index subgroups of $SL(2,\mathcal O_K)$ where $K$ is an imaginary quadratic field.

Much work has been done over discrete subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$, and similarly Eisenstein series on $SL(2,\mathcal O_K)$ itself, but I have not been able to locate this particular case.

Answer (score 4):

I do not recall off-hand whether J. Elstrodt, E. Grunewald,
J. Mennicke, *Eisenstein series on three-dimensional hyperbolic
spaces and imaginary quadratic fields*, J. reine und angew. Math. 
**360** (1985), 160–213 treats more general cases, but this is a standard reference, anyway.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The paper you mention seems only to treat the full Bianchi modular group $SL_2(O_K)$; and the poster specifically points out that he is aware of references for the full Bianchi modular group, but wants  for something treating more general finite-index subgroups of such groups.

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of the reference (and their book also), but most authors I've found have only been working over the full $SL_2(\mathcal O_K)$..

Comment: You can find some results for Eisenstein series for $\Gamma=\Gamma_0(q)$ and  $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ in Qi's paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.06026.pdf for example. He also has other papers on $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ where you may find something you want.